# link_to with single arg broken in mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, link-to

Just updated a Rails 3.2 application to Rails 4.2 and started getting a funny error.  Anytime I try to call `link_to` with a single argument inside my mailer template, I get an error.  However, I can make the same call just fine within one of my regular views.

Inside of my mailer view, I try to call it like this:

```
# user_mailer/notify.html.haml
...
= link_to "https://example.com"
```

But when the email gets processed by my job handler, it reports the error `ActionView::Template::Error: No route matches {:action=>"index"}`.  (Interestingly enough, this is what you get when you try to call `url_for` without any parameters).

However, on my homepage I have no issue using the same thing:

```
# home/index.html.haml
...
= link_to "https://example.com"
```

Outputs:

```
<a href="https://example.com">https://example.com</a>
```

As far as I can tell looking at the docs, nothing changed with `link_to` between Rails 3.2 and 4.2 so I'm confused why this would stop working... Also confused why it works in one place, but not the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) with just one parameter doesn't do what you think it does. If you look at the generated link in your view it just points to the site you're currently on. You have to provide two parameters, the body and the url.

```
= link_to "https://example.com"
# <a href="/">https://example.com</a>
```

You will need this however

```
= link_to "https://example.com", "https://example.com"
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense... I could've sworn it was different. Thanks for helping!